# php headers - post and follow

Tags: php, http-headers

Could someone help me on how to post variables and follow the post to that page?

Regards Phil

Comment: Do you want a PHP script to send an HTTP POST request to another page, or to get data that was sent by POST from the browser to your PHP script ? What do you mean by "follow the post" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CURL to do that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'bar' => 'goo');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myserver.com/post.php');

//post the data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//enable RETURN_TRANSFER so curl_exec() returns result of the request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an HTTP POST request via a redirect. You can do a GET redirect with parameters like this though:

```
header('Location: target_page.php?a=foo&b=bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data from one page to another and then redirect to that page, you can temporarily stash the data in the $_SESSION superglobal array and then redirect to the new page. once you're there you can then get the data back out of the array and unset() it if need be.